# how can i create a row with tree columns?

Tags: css, react-native

i want to create 3 columns, one of the i want to put in the left, and the second i want to put in the right and i want to create a button what cover the height of the  entire row and put follow to second element

with this code

```
 return (
        <View style={{ padding: 20, width: 370 }}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 30, color: '#9394B3' }}>hi</Text>
                <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 30, color: '#1D2359', textAlign: 'right' }}>hello</Text>

            </View>

            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 30, color: '#9394B3' }}>  hi2</Text>
                <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 30, color: '#1D2359', textAlign: 'right' }}>hello2</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                {addCoin && <Button onPress={() => addCoin(currentCoin, coinPrice)}> Add  </Button>}
            </View>
        </View>)
```

i have this result
[image]

this is my goal
[image]

the colums are not aligned
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
<View style={{ padding: 20, paddingTop: 50, flexDirection: 'row', width: '100%' }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 30, color: '#9394B3' }}>hi</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, lineHeight: 30, color: '#9394B3' }}> hi2</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 30, color: '#1D2359', textAlign: 'right' }}>hello</Text>
        <Text style={{ flex: 1, fontSize: 16, lineHeight: 30, color: '#1D2359', textAlign: 'right' }}>hello2</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Button title="Add" onPress={() => {}} />
      </View>
</View>
```

Comment: why hi2 is a little bit more to right?